# Popping Sound on Recorded Video Using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video

In my iOS app in Swift I am recording video, and some of the videos that are being recorded have a "Popping" sound at the very beginning of the video.  This only happens on certain devices, on other devices the sound works fine.  Anyone have any idea what may be causing this?  I've pasted my recording code below:

```
 func startRecording(frontCamera: Bool){

        //Don't start recording unless a video preview session is already running
        guard let session = captureSession else {return}
        guard session.isRunning else {return}

        print("STARTING RECORDING")
        startRecordingTimer()

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as NSURL? else {
            fatalError("documentDir Error")
        }
        let vidID = UUID().uuidString
        self.videoOutputID = vidID //Track the ID corresponding with the video.. this ID will be used to create the draft content
        let videoPath = vidID + ".mov"
        videoInputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(videoPath)
        let  movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: videoInputURL!.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: videoInputURL!.path)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
            }
        }

        let maxDuration: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: 600, timescale: 10)
        movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration
        print("MAX DURATION" , maxDuration.seconds)
        movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024


        if self.captureSession!.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput) {
            print("ADDING RECORDING OUTPUT")
            self.captureSession!.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
        }


        movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: videoInputURL!, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate!)

        if let device = currentCaptureDevice{
            setTorchMode(device:device)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I notice that you are modifying the session (calling `addOutput`) without calling `beginConfiguration` and `commitConfiguration`. That's a likely cause of trouble.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look into the documentation on setting that up properly and see if it helps